# Is the human lifespan still expanding?

Tags: human-biology, lifespan

**Description**

200 years ago, the human lifespan was roughly 35 to 40 years long. And it has *doubled* in length since then.

**Question**

Will the human lifespan continue to expand in length?

Comment: Is this question about maximum human lifespan, or about population lifespan as health and general living conditions improve?

Comment: @GrahamChiu it's a question about whether it's still expanding or if it's at it's maximum length.

Comment: And what does __it__ refer to?

Comment: @GrahamChiu the human lifespan...

Comment: So, you're asking about the maximum life span any human might attain? Like a 4 minute mile.

Comment: @GrahamChiu yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to ask whether or not humans will be able to continue increasing their life expectancy without an upper bound, the answer is no.  If you're asking if people live longer now than in the past and whether we can expect to see further increases, I'd guess that the answer is yes for most of the developed world, with the exception of the United States.  The same is probably true for most of the developing world; it would definitely be true in the developing world if western corporations started paying them fairly for their labor or resources, but that's getting into an answer for a different stack exchange website.

I suppose I should qualify the "no" to unbounded life expectancy, because it could come down to definitions of alive.  I don't think that it is outside the realm of possibility for science to provide techniques to artificially extend life; if we can start growing organs in labs, we might be able to just go change out our heart or kidneys much like we take our cars to have the tires changed. If you could figure out a way to take care of the circulatory / nervous system, too, who knows?  As it stands, though, our cells have an upper limit on the number of times that they can reproduce because we don't have enough telomerase in somatic cells to prevent the eventual shortening of telomeres (special sequence of base pairs located at the ends of DNA molecules) to the point where they no longer protect the DNA during replication and the cell eventually dies as a consequence. Hell, if we could just figure out how to take care of that we could probably chalk on some extra time - then we can see which system would be next to fail and take us out.

Comment: And drugs to lengthen telomeres?

Answer (score 5):

You will find here on the [UN World Population Prospects](https://esa.un.org/unpd/wpp/) plenty of data and visualization about change in life expectancy over time (among other things). The data also include predictions until year 2100.

For example, here is the life expectancy data and predictions over time for men in Morocco.

[image]

and here it is for women in Norway (note that x-axis range differs between the two graphs)

[image]

I picked two random countries but the general trend is very consistent among countries.

> Is the human lifespan still expanding?

Yes, life expectancy is still increasing in pretty much all countries and is expected to keep increasing.

Comment: What about maximum life span?

Comment: @GrahamChiu What do you mean? Are you asking about the change in the maximum lifespan through time or maybe about whether a theoretical asymptote should exist?

Comment: @Remi.b Not sure what is motivating the comments/question here but there was a recent paper (could be 5 years old now maybe? or older, time goes fast) that made a statistical argument that maximum lifespan reached a peak some years ago and has not risen since. That is, all gains in life expectancy since then have come by delaying earlier deaths, with no effect on prolonging the longest lives, and that new supercentenarian records are only because of increasing world population and nothing more. Sorry I don't have the reference.

Comment: There were also papers in response rebutting the original argument.

Comment: It might have been this one: *Dong, X., Milholland, B., & Vijg, J. (2016). Evidence for a limit to human lifespan. Nature, 538(7624), 257.* I'd also add that in the US life expectancy has dropped over the last couple of years. That doesn't necessarily mean the trend is not positive, of course.

Comment: Lifespan has obviously increased so I thought the question was asking about limits to maximum life span through time.  has that remained static since the appearance of the modern human?

Comment: @BryanKrause there's also this one, which I remember citing before the Dong paper came out: ( https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10522-008-9156-4 ).

When I ask questions like this to my mentors (I'm an undergraduate and have been working with aging for the last ~3 years), I usually get some variation on a long sigh. We can make other animals live a LOT longer than normal. And humans have been living longer *on average*, but our maximum hasn't changed much. Lifespan, especially human lifespan limits, is a really hard-to-pin-down thing.

Comment: Whilst the graphs show rising life expectancies the rate of growth *appears* to be slowing, ie would (were this purely a matter of statistics/mathematics) reach a peak and analysis might reveal when and how high. Of course it is not purely statistical; the underlying reasons for the rise are an accumulation of better food, living practices and medicine. Food and living practices are likely to reach a peak for extending lifespans - in places may have peaked already. Medicine remains a wild card that could deliver more, but not necessarily across the whole population.